# Text to Speech(TTS) JAVA API for mobile/blackberry applications

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, text-to-speech, jsapi

I'm developing the blackberry app, and in that I want to implement **TTS (Text-to-Speech)** functionality. I have seen **[JSAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Speech_API)**, it looks like it requires **synthesizer engine**.

So considering the mobile based applications keeping this sort engine and making the server side communications for all requests will lead into performance issue.

Can anyone know the JAVA API for achieving this for **blackberry** or any mobile applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this about the API for RIM [Text-To-Speech API](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/14530/Text-To-Speech_API_1024857_11.jsp).

Yes there are few API for your requirement.

[iSpeech Text to Speech (TTS) and Speech Recognition (ASR) SDK for BlackBerry](http://www.ispeech.org/developers/blackberry)

1. Make a Developer Account. and get the key, which is Free. From this you can get Two keys. One for Device and another for simulator.

   - when you check on simulator you must have to give the simulator key.
   - when you signIn on application replace the simulator key with the Device key.
     Click on Sample Application on that link.
2. click on iSpeech BlackBerry Demo to download the sample demo. Extract that zip file you can get the one Lib file. (if you want to do your own Add it to your application).

And get the key first because without getting the key the demo won't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are some 3rd party libraries and API which are used to convert TTS ( TEXT TO SPEECH ) in iphone

1) Sphinix ( Not Efficeint  )

2) Open-Ear ( Do not Required Internet Connectivity offline  TTS )

3) Google TTS (Requires Internet Connection)

4) Acapela (Not Free You Have to pay to get SDK)

5) Objective-C Speech Synthesizer Speak Engine (Do Not Required Internet Connectivity One of the Good offline TTS )

–What Is Open-Ear ?

Open-Ear is a shared and open source iOS frame Work for iphone text to speech conversion (TTS Synthesis).This Technology is used to convert English Text Into Speech for iphone .

–What is the best part in Open-Ear ?

This source is best because there’s no connectivity issue all processing takes place locally in the device mean you don’t need’s to connect to the internet.

Key Basic Concepts and Tips :

1 ) FliteController creates synthesized speech text to speech (TTS).

–Now what is Flite Controller ?

Its an class which controls speech Sysnthesis that is text to speech in Open-Ears.